# Restore broken branch/resolve detached HEAD state?

Tags: git, branch, commit

After restarting my computer, 'git commit' & 'git status' both return an error message:

`error: bad signature`

`fatal: index file corrupt`

running 'git branch':

`fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref.`

running 'git log':

`fatal: your current branch appears to be broken`

What causes this?
How can I restore/fix my local repo/branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me.

1. Re-clone the repository into another directory.
2. Copy the `.git` folder from newly cloned repo & replace the one in the original repo.

This will repair the detached HEAD state which occurred as a result of (in this particular case) uncommitted changes that were discarded (but saved locally) when computer was forced to shut down.

Comment: Where can I find the .git folder from the newly cloned repo?

Comment: It should be in the root directory of your repository. Depending on your settings and what you are using (file explorer or terminal) it may be hidden.